# How to handle child row in table sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am  using TableSorter 2.10.8 ,

In my code there are many child rows, which are toggling under some conditions, one sample is given below.
and

```
<tbody>
<tr class="historyView historyViewClosed">
<tr class="historyView historyViewClosed">
<tr  class="historyView historyViewOpen">

</tr>
<tr  class="historyView tablesorter-childRow">
</tr>
</tbody>
```

So when using pager for pagination, all  tags are been hidden except the one with class `tablesorter-childRow` or we can say child row will be visible in next page.

how can I make child row to be hidden in next page.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in tablesorter v2.15.12 ([issue reference](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/396#issuecomment-39077374)). The child-row is now grouped with its parent and will not show on other pages.

This can be controlled by using the [`countChildRows` pager option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-countchildrows) (Boolean) which when `false` (default) will group the child row with the parent ignoring the pager page size setting.

When `true`, the child rows will count towards the pager page size and will potentially split the child rows across pages, as it was before the fix.

I would recommend updating to the latest version of tablesorter (fork) as there have been many bug fixes and enhancements since version 2.10.8 ([change log](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Changes)).